# Flutter "exited" after saving some configuration and doesn't hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, hot-reload

[This is the image before I restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooo12.png)
[and this is what happened after I save some change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3KKA.png)

Image one is before and image two is after.

I tried already flutter channel master or beta
even tried to flutter clean, flutter upgrade and still no use.

Comment: "Flutter web currently supports hot restart but not hot reload." https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/hot-reload. Just so that you know. I don't know what the problem with the "exited" is.